# how to post text '&nsbp ' using javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, post

The content that i want to send

```
<div id="preview">&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp</div>
```

Element function:

```
function _(obj) {
    return document.getElementById(obj);
}
```

Ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://<?php echo $domain ?>/libraries/ajax/pdf.php',
    data: 'html=' + _("preview").innerHTML + '&nama=a',
    dataType: 'html',
    beforeSend: function() {},
    success: function(response) {
        Materialize.toast((response), 4000);
    }
});
```

How to send `&nsbp` as text instead of `POST` parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `encodeURIComponent(<string to be encoded>)` to encode the data

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
data: { html: _("preview").innerHTML, nama: 'a'}
```

And `$.ajax` will encode it. Under the hood, it uses uses this `encodeURIComponent()`, you use it like

```
data: 'html='+encodeURIComponent(_("preview").innerHTML)+'&nama=a',
```